SQLCipher giving "file is not a database" error when app is killed after SQLCipher update v4.5.6
I am upgrading my android project from library net.zetetic:android-database-sqlcipher:3.5.9@aar to  net.zetetic:sqlcipher-android:4.5.6@aar. It runs fine after updating, but while running, if we killed the app from recent tabs, it starts giving this error from every next launch.
I made all the necessary changes as per the documentation, but this case is different and had no solution given. My code is as follows:
The constructor has been modified and inserted hooks to migrate sqlcipher.
private DbHelper(Context context) {
    super(context,
            databaseName,
            password,
            null,
            databaseVersion,
            1,
            null,
            new SQLiteDatabaseHook() {
                @Override
                public void preKey(SQLiteConnection connection) {

                }

                @Override
                public void postKey(SQLiteConnection connection) {
                    connection.executeRaw("PRAGMA cipher_compatibility=3;", null, null);
                    connection.executeRaw("PRAGMA kdf_iter=1000;", null, null);
                    connection.executeRaw("PRAGMA cipher_default_kdf_iter=1000;", null, null);
                    connection.executeRaw("PRAGMA cipher_migrate;", null, null);
                }
            },
            false);
}

As per the documentation, the hooks should only be executed for the first time of migration. SO I have two separated constructors to take care of this condition and the condition is working as expected. Following is another constructor:
private DbHelper(Context context, String secondLaunchCase) {
    super(context, databaseName, password, null, databaseVersion, 1 , null, null, false);
}

I am encrypting the database password and saving it in file. And using the same password to pass in the constructor above. I verified that password is going the same each time. ALso, for the fresh install, everything is working fine.
I am not getting how it affects this if the app is killed? Please help with this.

According to my experiment, I believe the DB file migration process could be a standalone method, independent of the DBHelper's constructor.
Here's my approach:
Create a instance of hook
SQLiteDatabaseHook hook = new SQLiteDatabaseHook() {
    @Override
    public void preKey(SQLiteConnection connection) {
    }

    @Override
    public void postKey(SQLiteConnection connection) {
        connection.executeRaw("PRAGMA cipher_migrate", null, null);
    }
};

Do the DB file migration
SQLiteDatabase db = null;
    try {
        File olderFormatDatabase = context.getDatabasePath(APP_DATABASE_NAME);
        db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(olderFormatDatabase.getAbsolutePath(),
                password,
                null,
                SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE | SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY,
                hook);
    } catch (SQLiteException sqliteException) {
       // error handle
    } finally {
        if(db != null)
            db.close();
    }

Then the DBHelper constructor can function without the hook instance.
Perhaps this approach could be helpful.
